# Como cambiar un fragmento dependiendo el item selecionado

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo una lista donde tengo varias opciones y alado aparece la descripción, pero no se como puedo hacer que el fragmento que contiene la descripción cambien de acuerdo al item que yo selecciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es tu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que dar más información.

Tienes una actividad y dos fragmentos A y B. El fragment A contiene la lista y el fragmento B contiene la descripción. Este es el típico caso Maestro-Detalle. La forma que tendrías que cargar la información del Fragmento A al Fragmento B sería a través de la actividad. El fragmento A envía la información a la actividad y la actividad se lo envía al fragmento B.

También se podría hacer con eventos/bus, pero te aconsejaría antes que vieras cómo trabajan conjuntamente las actividades y fragmentos.

Saludos.